# Apache POI is using too much RAM in XLSM files

Tags: java, report, ram, xlsm

Recently I was working on a report using Java and Apache Poi which had macro in the xls file template, however the amount of data that was sometimes generated exceeded the capabilities of the xls format, in order for the macro to work I decided to use the xlsm format and HSSF org.apache.poi.hssf. When using xls file, the RAM consumption was 1.5 GB, but after changes in code it changed to 15GB RAM, where the logic of the report has not been changed, if I change only the template to xlsx format, the report again needs 1.5 - 2GB RAM, is it possible to do something to make the RAM consumption in XLSM format lower?